# format float number to 17 chars - Python

Tags: python

I'm new to Python, and I'm struggling to format a number to 17 chars including the decimal point.

example:

```
100.00
```

result:

```
 0000000100.000000
```

I tried `.zfill(17)`, but it only displays one digit after the decimal point.

Comment: You many decimals do you want? Always 6?

Comment: Yes. I need to always have 6 decimals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`str.format`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
>>> '{:017.6f}'.format(100.00)
'0000000100.000000'
```

or [`format`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format):

```
>>> format(100.00, '017.6f')
'0000000100.000000'
```

Answer (score 1):

I like this:

```
In [42]: '%017.6f'%100
Out[42]: '0000000100.000000'
```